# Preventive vs Confrontive mechanisms

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I call (and I'm not alone in this idea) a mechanism that protects a system from entry by malicious users a **preventive** mechanism. On the other side, what should I call a mechanism that deals with intruders *already within* the system by analyzing their behaviors - and based on the findings, identifies them for further decisions/actions?

I think it could be called as **confrontive** mechanism. Is this term appropriate? Any idea for better terms?

Comment: A ***selective*** mechanism? This can be an opinion-based issue though,

Comment: Is *confrontive* an appropriate term to describe a mechanism that...,?

Comment: The closest I can think of is 'watchdog', though you might not like the register. It is often used metaphorically, and often for the monitoring of situations rather than [just] their preclusion. 'Confrontive' means that action is taken (not just monitoring done). 'Watchdog' does not preclude this, though it does not entail it.

Comment: Surveillance? User analysis?

Comment: @JulieCarter - Surveillance sounds good.

Comment: Clearly, I mean for per-incident situations preventive mechanisms are used and for post-incident situations, confrontive ones. Of course, there is no definition for _confrontive_ in M-W and Oxford dictionary. So, I think the terms may be changed to preventional and confrontational mechanisms.

Comment: A ***firewall*** stops unwanted users/software from getting *into* your computer. ***Malware cleaning*** packages detect and remove unwanted software that's already got past the firewall. The first is a "preventive" approach, the second is "curative".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, good idea! It can be accepted as correct answer. Why confrontational (confrontive) is not appropriate? There is a consideration that makes me doubtful for curative. Such mechanisms may be unsuccessful in detecting and removing all malicious things. In this regard, curative has a positive connotation while confrontive is more neutral and does not guarantee any perfect result.

Comment: @Eilia: Derivatives of *confront* simply don't work so well as those based on *cure* for your context. I think because the "target" is inanimate/non-sentient, and to *confront* is akin to *challenge, oppose*, in that it's more likely to be used in contexts where two foes are actively (and consciously) battling against each other. A doctor might *tackle* or *treat* your disease in order to *cure* it, but he probably wouldn't *confront* or *stand up to* it. You yourself might confront your problems, but usually there's the implication that what you're "facing up to" is your own inner "inertia".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer industry has long used the analogy of *infected* systems. You could rely upon this well-established trope, and make a distinction between  *preventative* and *therapeutic* measures, and refer to an *observational* phase during which you attempt to determine the nature of the thing that is infecting the system.

What you need to steer clear of is mixing martial metaphors with medical metaphors, for then you have a trope and a meta-trope, so to speak.

As an alternative, you can refer to the observational phase as the "discovery" phase, or you could say that during the *heuristic* phase you seek to determine the nature of the infection.

Comment: Specifically adjectives are welcomed. For example, as said in the comments and OP, preventive and curative/confrontive approaches or mechanisms. Then, what adjectives are suggested for discovery and heuristic?

Comment: *Heuristic* is already an adjective, and *discovery*, a noun, can be used attributively as an adjective: "the discovery phase", "a discovery mechanism", "a discovery approach".

Comment: Another issue is that such phase in addition to discovery, tries to deal with the detected problem(s) in some way. In this regard, discovery/heuristic cannot support the underlying idea, IMO.

Comment: You said that at this phase you were not taking remedial action, merely identifying the culprits and their behaviors, for future action. Identifying the problem and eradicating the problem are separate things, right?

Comment: In fact, these two groups of actions may be performed within same phase. Can we have an adjective for that?

Comment: As in medicine, diagnosis and treatment are separate things.

Comment: Of course, **Theranostics** is an exception.

Comment: @Eilia: Good one :)  But *diagnosis* and *treatment* are still discrete functions even though the nano-particles can do both.  They had to coin that word.  If coinage is allowed here, the door opens.